# Why is a Mongo Id pushed to array instead of an Object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating my first backend project with Node.js. I am building a stock trading app with Express 4, and Mongoose.The User has a list of stock objects `{symbol: amount}`. When the user wants to buy a stock, they send a POST request with stock, an amount, and a verb in this case 'buy'. In the Post, 
I take the stock and amount from the request body and add it to the User's stock list, and also add the data to a list of actions. I POST a request with `{stock: 'F', amount: '2', verb: 'buy'}` so the resulting stock list should be `stocks:[{'F': '2'}]` and

```
actions: [{"time": "2015-01-20T19:07:15.000Z",
            "verb": "buy",
            "amount": 2,
            "stock": "P",}]
```

When I do `user.stocks.push(stockObject);` user.stocks becomes `[{ _id: 54be8739dd63f94c0e000004 }]` instead of `[{'F': '2'}]` and the action list becomes 
    "actions": [
            {
                "time": "2015-01-20T19:07:15.000Z",
                "verb": "buy",
                "amount": 2,
                "stock": "P",
                "_id": "54bea763589e571f0f000004"
            }] 
with an _id added to it.
Why is the stock list only getting an object with an id, when the action list is getting the full object with an id?

```
var UserSchema   = new Schema({
    id: String,        
    stocks: [{
        symbol: String,
        amount: Number
    }]
});

router.route('/user/:user_id/action')
.post(function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({           
        id: req.params.user_id
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) res.send(err);
        var stock = req.body.stock;
        var amount = req.body.amount;
        var stockObject = {};
        if(req.body.verb === 'buy') {
            stockObject[stock] = amount;
        } 
        var action = {
            time: Date(),
            verb: req.body.verb,
            amount: req.body.amount,
            stock: req.body.stock
        }
        user.stocks.push(stockObject);
        user.actions.push(action);                                  
        user.save(function(err) {                                   
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json({ actions: user.actions, stocks: user.stocks });                                      
        });

    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you reference an object inside another model in `mongoose`, it just keeps the `id` of the referenced object.

If you want to retrieve the referenced object attributes, you have to use the [populate method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate).

Comment: does this mean that anytime I want to access the user's stock list in need to  User.findOne({ id: user_id}).populate('stocks').exec(err, user)

Comment: It's an option. But you can also define a `static` method inside your `User` schema, let's say `findById`, where you could call `findOne` with the `populate` option. Then, everytime you call that method, you'll have the nested object list populated.